# Custom cursor on a element (behind?) a input

Tags: css, bulma

I use Bulma and I would like to be able to see the pointer cursor on the right icon in the input field.

```css
.main {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.is-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
      <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="icon is-small is-right is-clickable">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to see the cursor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ignores the cursor movement, because `pointer-events: none` has been added by Bulma. As you can see:

[image]

It needs to be `pointer-events: auto;` to see the cursor movement. You can find more information about `pointer-events` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Also, icon is not behind the input.

```css
.main {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.is-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
      <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="icon is-small is-right is-clickable">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason it will not allow me to set a custom cursor on an `input` element, even with `!important`?